# Roads API snapped polyline just a straight line

Tags: google-roads-api

i currently working with roads API and try to use lat long from my database for the path. but the polylines just draw a straight line between the points and is not following the road

```
function runSnapToRoad() {
 var pathValues = [];
@foreach($transaction as $transac)
pathValues.push("{{$transac->latitude}},{{$transac->longitude}}"); 
@endforeach

$.get('https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads', {
 interpolate: true,
 key: apiKey,
 path: pathValues.join('|')
}, function(data) {
processSnapToRoadResponse(data);
drawSnappedPolyline();
});
}
```

the pathValues[] returns perfectly the points but the polylines where just straight between the points. how can i obtain snapped polylines(lines drawn based on the roads.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just found out that the points(lat,lng) requested should not have a long distance between them. snapped roads is obtained when points are tight.